# linear independence with a set of 3 vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If a set of $3$ vectors $\{u,v,w\}$ is linearly independent, then it means that each vector cannot be a linear combination of the other $2$ vectors.

For example, $u \neq c_1v + c_2w$ and so on.

However, would these rules apply when adding or subtracting from itself?

For example, If $\{u,v,w\}$ is linearly independent, would the set of vectors $\{u, u-v, v+w \}$ be linearly independent as well?

I'm not sure if the same rule would apply so that we can have $u \neq c_1u - c_2v$ and such.

Comment: Put the vectors in a matrix and notice that doing elementary row operations doesn't change the rank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they would be linearly independent as well. In fact, if $\alpha u+\beta(u-v)+\gamma(v+w)=0$, then$$(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)u+(-\beta+\gamma)v+\gamma w=0.$$But then, since the set $\{u,v,w\}$ is linearly independent, we have$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0\\-\beta+\gamma=0\\\gamma=0\end{array}\right.$$and this occurs if and only if $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$.